# How can I fix this CORS error using javascript?

Tags: javascript, http, post, cors

Hey guys I am fairly new to programming so this is probably a very easy solution but I keep getting a CORS error when trying to run this program. (the api key was blocked for my safety). This code is pretty unorganized but once I can get a request working I will create an object for all the values.

This is the error I get with a live-server from the Chrome console:

Access to fetch at 'https://labelsupply.io/api/order' from origin 'http://127.0.0.1:8080' has been blocked by CORS policy: Response to preflight request doesn't pass access control check: The value of the 'Access-Control-Allow-Credentials' header in the response is '' which must be 'true' when the request's credentials mode is 'include'.

Here is the code for the POST request

```
document.querySelector('.btn-order').addEventListener('click', function(){
    
    Type = document.querySelector('#type').value;
    Weight = document.querySelector("#weight").value;
    FromCountry = "US";
    FromName = document.querySelector('#fromName').value;
    FromCompany = document.querySelector('#fromCompany').value;
    FromStreet = document.querySelector('#fromStreet').value;
    FromStreet2 = document.querySelector('#fromStreet2').value;
    FromCity = document.querySelector('#fromCity').value;
    FromState = document.querySelector('#fromState').value;
    FromZip = document.querySelector('#fromZip').value;
    ToCountry = 'US';
    ToName = document.querySelector('#ToName').value;
    ToCompany = document.querySelector('#ToCompany').value;
    ToStreet = document.querySelector('#ToStreet').value;
    ToStreet2 = document.querySelector('#ToStreet2').value;
    ToCity = document.querySelector('#ToCity').value;
    ToState = document.querySelector('#ToState').value;
    ToZip = document.querySelector('#ToZip').value;

    console.log(Type, Weight, FromCountry, FromName, FromCompany, FromStreet, FromStreet2, FromCity, FromState, FromZip);


    const data = {
        Type: '32854090-03dd-a3c1-a8c5-183d17a6e9a6',
        Weight: '12',
        FromCountry: 'US',
        FromName: '',
        FromCompany: '',
        FromStreet: '',
        FromStreet2: '',
        FromCity: '',
        FromState: '',
        FromZip: '',
        ToCountry: 'US',
        ToName: '',
        ToCompany: '',
        ToStreet: '',
        ToStreet2: '',
        ToCity: '',
        ToState: '',
        ToZip: ''
      };
      
      const headers = {
        'Content-Type': 'application/www-x-form-urlencoded',
        'X-Api-Auth': '000000000-0000000-000000-000000000',
        'Access-Control-Allow-Credentials': true
      };
      
      // Encode the data as a query string
      const queryString = new URLSearchParams(data).toString();
      
      fetch('https://labelsupply.io/api/order', {
        method: 'POST',
        headers: headers,
        credentials: 'include',
        body: queryString
      })
      .then(response => response.json())
      .then(data => {
        console.log(data);
      })
      .catch(error => {
        console.log(error);
      });
      
        
    })
```

I have tried using - credentials: 'include' but this results in the same error. I also have tried using lots of different header types. Maybe there is a better way to fix this CORS error. Any tips for any of my code will be helpful.

Thank you in advance :)

Comment: You can't fix the problem on the client side. You have to fix it on the server side.

Comment: Is `labelsupply.io/api` a public api? Anyways, assuming perhaps this is the company you work for and you're just trying to hit the production API locally for some reason... you can proxy requests from `localhost:8080/api` to `labelsupply.io/api` and change your `fetch(...` to `fetch('/api/order', ...`

Answer (score -1):

> This is a common issue, this happens if the server is not configured
> to allow requests from the domain making the request, or if the client
> is making a request to a server that does not support CORS.
>
> You have to run the code on the server side because these errors occur
> only on client-side requests which the server cannot accept
> you request unless the server is configured to receive such requests.

Answer (score -2):

You need to enable CORS.
Make an HTTP request from a server.
Use a proxy server